# String.Substring(start, end) sometimes throwing an exception

Tags: vb.net, inheritance, reflection, backgroundworker

My program uses a [BackgroundWorker](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to call a `PerformAction()` method when a different method, `Method1` returns true. I also am using the [Strategy Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern) to set the correct `PerformAction()` that should be performed every time the event is raised.

For the Strategy Pattern I created an Abstract Class, and then a class inside the abstract class that inherits it.

```
Public  MustInherit Class Abstract
    Public MustOverride Sub PerformAction(ByVal str as String)
    Public Class Extends
           Inherits Abstract
            Public Overrides Sub PerformAction(ByVal str as String)
                str = str.Substring(str.IndexOf(":"), str.IndexOf(">"))
                MsgBox(str)
            End Sub
End Class
```

I create another class that contains a field of Abstract, and that is used to call PerformAction.

The PerformAction method gets called from the BackgroundWorker.ReportProgress event, which is called when BackgroundWorker.DoWork detects that `Method1` is returning true. And with the code above, it causes a `System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException` with addition information *Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation*.

The debugger tells me:

```
    this    Cannot obtain value of local or argument '<this>' as it is not available at this instruction pointer, possibly because it has been optimized away.  System.Delegate

    args    Cannot obtain value of local or argument 'args' as it is not available at this instruction pointer, possibly because it has been optimized away.    object[]
```

Strangely enough, when I perform (what seems to me) an identical operation with two substrings:

```
s = s.Substring(s.IndexOf(":"))
s = s.Substring(0, s.IndexOf(">"))
```

it functions perfectly.

What is the difference between these two methods? Is my inheritance set up incorrectly and that is what is causing these errors? What's going on here?

Let me know if I need to add more code to explain the situation. Thanks.

Comment: The second argument in the `SubString` method is the **length** of the substring, not the index of the last character.

Comment: Something like `s.Substring(s.IndexOf(":"), s.IndexOf(">") - s.IndexOf(":"))` or of course assign `s.IndexOf(":")` to a variable and use that...

Answer (score 1):

To get the effect of

```
s = s.Substring(s.IndexOf(":"))
s = s.Substring(0, s.IndexOf(">"))
```

in a single statement, you need to calculate the length of the desired substring

```
s = s.SubString(s.IndexOf(":"), s.IndexOf(">") - s.IndexOf(":"))
```

Note that if it is possible that the string does not contain a ":" followed later by a ">", you will need to first verify that `IndexOf(":")` is >= 0 and that `s.IndexOf(">")` returns a value greater than `IndexOf(":")`.

Comment: Shoot. Well that's my old Java roots coming back to haunt me.
Any idea why it throws a `System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException` and not a `IndexOutOfRangeException`?

Comment: @Django I don't know why that exception. I wasn't sure if the code you posted was your actual code. `s` is not declared, the result of the `SubString` method is being ignored (not assigned to a variable) and the `PerformAction` sub doesn't appear to do anything.

Comment: Just copied the code incorrectly, I just fixed it in the post. The exception is raised in both versions.

Comment: @Django - You might check to see if the the `InnerException` is set.  That might provide more information or even have the `IndexOutOfRangeException`.

Comment: @ChrisDunaway That is absolutely what it is. I just intentionally threw a `NullPointException` and it gave me the same `TargetInvocationException`. I will look into `InnerException`, thanks for the answer.